# jquery code for checkbox in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This jQuery function is always returning true in `alert(isChecked)`, even when unchecked:
     pls note .accrualCheckbox is the class name of Div , not the class that is set for check box. I removed the code if ($(this).prop('checked', 'checked')), now it is always returning as 'false'

```
$('.accrualCheckbox').click(function () {
    var isChecked = $(this).attr('checked') ? true : false;
    alert($(this).attr('checked'));
    alert(isChecked);
    if ($(this).prop('checked', 'checked')) {
        var parentDiv = $(this).parents('.searchLine');
        $(parentDiv).css('border', '1px solid red');

        //Checkbox
        $(parentDiv).find("input[type=text]").each(function () {
            $(this).val('B');
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        });
    }
});
});
```

I kept the check box in the div:

```
<div class="accrualCheckbox">
    @Html.CheckBox("chkSalesAndMarketing")
</div>
```

Comment: What does the last }); correspond to? I'm confused why it's there.

Comment: @phileaton I rolled back your edit because it's not a "fix", it's a matter of personal preference. The way he had it is just as much of a standard as what you changed it to. It's his post, so it should be left in his preferred style.

Comment: If anything needs to be fixed, it's the apparent extra final closing `});` at the end of the first code block. @user2543573, why is that there?

Comment: @AdiInbar probably because the code is inside the document ready handler and he accidentally copied the closing along with the function he wanted to post

Comment: @koala_dev Yes, *probably*, but I asked rather than deleting it because I think it's generally a bad idea to correct code in an edit, because it's possible that what you're fixing might have something to do with the problem, or might have a purpose you weren't aware of. No, I don't think either one is the case here, but as a rule I never edit code in a question beyond fixing formatting issues without checking with the poster first. If you monkey around with the posted code, you risk changing the question.

Comment: @AdiInbar I agree, it shouldn't be edited out

Comment: sorry for confusion ,

Comment: Adi and phileaton :sorry , that was the closing for document.ready function in which the whole code is put.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `prop()` instead of `attr()` or you can also do:

```
var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
```

But this `if ($(this).prop('checked', 'checked'))` will always return true since you're setting the value to `checked` inside the condition

**UPDATE**
I assume this is what you want to do:

```
$('.accrualCheckbox :checkbox').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {  // or $(this).prop('checked');
        var parentDiv = $(this).closest('.searchLine');
        $(parentDiv).css('border', '1px solid red');
        //Checkbox
        $(parentDiv).find(":text").each(function () {
            $(this).val('B');
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: pls note .accrualCheckbox is the class name of Div , not the class that is set for check box. I removed the code if ($(this).prop('checked', 'checked')), now it is always returning as 'false'

Comment: @user2543573 please add that detail to your question, and if you just want to handle the click on the checkbox just update the selector for the click handler like this `$('.accrualCheckbox :checkbox').click(function...`

Comment: thanks, it is working now by ur change.i update this as Answer.

Comment: i added that details to questuion also.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).prop('checked')` instead of `attr()`.

See the attributes vs. properties section here: http://api.jquery.com/prop/